# how to only autolayout iPhone6 +

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout

There is a full screen UI in my application. It looks good except iPhone6 Plus. In order to auto layout iPhone 4S. So the UI looks too small in Phone6 Plus. I tried to use the "size Class", but it just support 3.5-inch,4-inch,4.7-inch or all. It will cover other operations when i use "base values".May be I use method is wrong. Please refer to the following Pictures. Sorry i only post 2 links.

6sPlus
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15fXC.jpg)

5s
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71DSu.jpg)

How to solve the UI problem in my application. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! You might find it useful to review these links when you have a chance: Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure if there any changes bw those two screenshots. So if you want the same ui in all screen first give all your constraints with size class disabled. After constraints are applied enable size class. If constraints given are right, it'll works.